# ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED on Android Background Service

Tags: java, android, service

I'm trying to create a service which starts when I plug the battery charger and stop when unplug it. The problem is when I unplug the charger my service don't stop while when I plug it's all fine.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)){
            Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)){
            Intent j = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.stopService(j);
        }

        }
}
```

**Here is my Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Does it actually receive that action? How are you registering this Receiver?

Comment: please share your manifest file where you declared the receiver

Comment: Updated my question with the manifest.

Comment: Code looks good. How do you know the service is not stopping?

Comment: I store data like GPS coordinates to firebase. So I want when to unplug the charger my service stops and also stop sending data to the base. But actually that didn't happen and I know that my service still running.

Comment: Tip: Add `@greeble31` to your comment so I get a notification in my inbox.

Comment: At this point, I think you need to do some old-fashioned debugging. It seems very unlikely that, after a call to `context.stopService()`, the service is still running. One of 3 things is happening: 1.) The service _is_ stopping, but you have code somewhere else that restarts it, 2.) The service _is_ stopping, but your procedure to determine this by monitoring Firebase (vs. a more direct method, like a breakpoint) is flawed, or 3.) `stopService()` is not actually being called. You will need to determine for yourself what is happening; the code posted here offers no clues.